# macbook trackpad only registering long clicks (ignores quick clicks)

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, click

I've been getting frustrated with my 2012 macbook air running el capitan.

My trackpad no longer registers clicking in the sense of a 'regular' quick click. Out of frustrated, I started applying more pressure and that would often work but after some more experimenting, I discovered that it's not a pressure issue, but a delay issue.

With a 'quick click' I can get maybe every 5th click to register. However, if I only my click down for almost a second, it registers nearly every time. (turns out that when I was using the 'lots of pressure' technique, I was also prolonging the length of the click, hence I erroneously thought it was an issue of pressure.)

I haven't been able to find this particular issue mentioned. Anyone have any theories and based on the description, would this be more hardware or software related?

Comment: What happens if you boot into Safe Mode or Recovery Mode?  Does the problem still exist?

Comment: @Allan looks like the problem is there even in safe mode (Though I'm noticing safe mode has all sorts of different issues...namely screen redrawing glitches...)

Comment: At this point, I would run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: @Allan hmm...I rant AHT and got a SATA (HD) error. Crap. Another issue. In investigating that, someone suggested a SMC reset. That...actually seems to have helped with the track pad clicking...the delay is less...though still there. So, I dunno. Between this issue and the HD going I guess it's time I cough up a grand and get a new laptop. (Which, to be fair, is somewhat expected every 5 years. :)

Comment: It could all be due to a failing HDD.  You don't *need* to replace it to do diags.  Get a cheap USB flash (16/32GB) and install macOS on that.  If it boots and operates with no problems, you found the issue.  A new SSD is significantly cheaper than a new MacBook

Comment: @Allan oh! That's interesting...so the HD could be causing the clicking issue. Hmm...

Comment: You may be perceiving a clicking issue when it's a general system latency issue overall.  That's my theory, at least.

Comment: @allan think it's worth replacing the SSD or just time for a new MacBook?